# Performance difference between fundamental type and class type

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a new basic type, for example `byte`:

The first idea is to use

```
enum class byte: unsigned char { };
```

However, this approach has a problem that I cannot define assignment operator for it, so assignment from `int` cannot be done:

```
byte a = 42; // invalid, need to use something like "byte a = (byte)42;"
```

The second idea is to use a class:

```
class byte {
    private:
        unsigned char data;
    public:
        // operators
};
```

This approach could work, but I worry about the performance of this.

My questions:

- Is there any rule in the standard, which makes my `byte` type less optimizable than `unsigned char`?
- What is the current state of popular compilers (gcc, clang, msvc) on popular platforms (windows, intel-linux, android, iOS) optimizing this? Are they good enough currently to emit the same code for `byte` and `unsigned char`? I'm interested in any differences.

The only difference I know is that on platforms which use the i386 System V ABI (like 32-bit linux), `byte` is returned on stack, instead of register from functions, so it is a little bit less performant. Are there any more differences?

Comment: If you worry about performance then measure it. You are worried about how things are being returned? Heck, they might not be returned at all when inlining or other optimizations are involved. Compile the code and see for yourself.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qLm0d4

Comment: @asynts: I want to create a new type. For whatever reason, there can be any. Strong typedef is a usual demand.

Comment: @tkausl: https://godbolt.org/z/HcdUfX

Comment: @freakish: this is a general question, I cannot measure it.

Comment: Inline operators come without any performance penalty(\*) as there is no code for function call generated. (\*): In general, at least; large inline functions used at many different places might blow up the programme that much that cache paging comes into play - and performance is gone...

Comment: Side note: for complex data types, you might rely on perfect forwarding, though.

Comment: The short answer is:  it depends.    If the compiler has visibility of the definitions of all member functions (operators, constructors) when compiling code that uses the class, the standard (for the most part) neither requires nor forbids the compiler from inlining those functions at the call site.   Whether a compiler actually does inline, or not, is related to quality of implementation of that compiler.     In any event, focus on getting your code working correctly first (in the sense that inputs give required outputs, etc) and then profile/test to see *if* there is a performance hit.